# How to do a paginated crawl?

Tags: web-scraping, scrape.it-wsl

I am trying to run the following which is goto flipkart, crawl all the product links and extract product, price and description. However, this only grabs one page only, I want to repeat the crawl across all pages ex) page 1, 2, 3...etc

```
GOTO flipkart.com/search?q=laptops&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off
CRAWL //div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div//div[1]/a[@class="_2cLu-l"][1]
EXTRACT {
  "product": "//span[@class=\"_35KyD6\"][1]",
  "price": "//div[@class=\"_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1\"][1]",
  "description": "//div[@class=\"_3u-uqB\"][1]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend the paginator with `[[xpath_for_nextpage_element]]`.

In this case the xpath for the "next page" link is `//nav/a[11]/span`. You wrap `[[` and `]]` around it and put it right after the `CRAWL` statement.

So we get: `[[//nav/a[11]/span]]`.

```
GOTO flipkart.com/search?q=laptops&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off
CRAWL [[//nav/a[11]/span]] //div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div//div[1]/a[@class="_2cLu-l"][1]
EXTRACT {
  "product": "//span[@class=\"_35KyD6\"][1]",
  "price": "//div[@class=\"_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1\"][1]",
  "description": "//div[@class=\"_3u-uqB\"][1]"
}
```

This is essentially now a scraper that will grab all the product information.